# get preference of language in System Preferences-> language & text

Tags: shell, applescript, locale, system-preferences

I'd like to get the preference of language in  System Preferences-> language & text.  I try to use "get system info" to get the language preference.

```
set language_prefer to (user locale of (get system info))
if (language_prefer is "zh-Hans") then
   set sharingstr to "共享"
   set startstr to "启动"
else if (language_prefer is "zh-Hant") then
   set sharingstr to "共享"
   set startstr to "啟動"
else
   set sharingstr to "Sharing"
   set startstr to "Start"
end if
```

But i found that the (user locale of (get system info)) return value never changes when i change preference of language.  Then i found that the user locale is different to preference language. **Take Simplified Chinese as example, it's user locale is "zh_CN", but it's language preference is "zh-Hans".** Someone says that use

```
set lang to do shell script "defaults read NSGlobalDomain AppleLanguages"
```

this returns

```
(
"zh-Hans",
en,
"zh-Hant",
de,
ja,
fr,
es,
it,
pt,
"pt-PT",
nl,
sv,
nb,
da,
fi,
ru,
pl,
ko,
ar,
cs,
hu,
tr
)
```

How can i get the language preference value such as "zh-Hans"?

Wish someone help me, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Cocoa/Objective C "`NSLocale`" documentation, I see there are actually ***two*** user level locale variables.

One is [`currentLocale`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSLocale/currentLocale) and the other is [`autoupdatingCurrentLocale`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSLocale/autoupdatingCurrentLocale).

Unfortunately for you, it looks like the API Apple has decided to export via AppleScript is the one that only updates at the user's login time.  I suspect your Applescript result will only change each time the user is rebooted or re-logged in.

You will need to come up with an Objective C tool that allows you to do "`autoupdatingCurrentLocale`" and put that into an Applescript variable.

Now I see you've edited your question, so I'll edit mine as well: It sounds like what you want to do is what has been suggested [in the answers of this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160462/get-language-of-currently-logged-in-user-via-applescript), which I'm pretty certain you've seen while doing your own research.  Use that "`get_language()`" applescript bit to return item 1 of your "`r`" array.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but as i have tried : the user locale is different from language preference.Take Simplified Chinese as example, it's user locale is "zh_CN", but it's language preference is "zh-Hans".

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple different locale settings:

- `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print AppleLanguages:0' ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist`

  - First language selected in Language & Text > Language
- `defaults read -g AppleLocale`

  - Setting selected in Language & Text > Region
  - `user locale of (system info)`
  - Determines what Terminal and iTerm set the LC_ variables to by default
- First item in AppleLanguages in `/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist`

  - Changed by `sudo languagesetup` and when running Setup Assistant
  - Language used in the login window and for new users and the guest user
- `defaults read /Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist AppleLocale`

  - Changed when running Setup Assistant
  - Region used for new users and the guest user